# Compactness of Sobolev embedding for domains of finite measure

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a domain of finite Lebesgue measure, not assumed to be smooth or bounded. Is it true that the embedding of, say, $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ (Sobolev functions with zero boundary value) into $L^q(\Omega)$ is compact for $1/q > 1/p - 1/d$?

Comment: There are necessary and sufficient conditions on $\Omega$ for  the compactness of such embedding. Check Mazy'a's book *Sobolev Spaces*, Springer Verlag, 2011,  Section 5.5.2.

Comment: Since you want this only for functions with compact support, the embedding theorem follows directly from the one for functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Deane, I am not sure I follow your argument here. There is no compact embedding for functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Could you axpand what do you mean here, I am sure I misunderstand something.

Comment: @Andras  There is no compact embedding on $\mathbb{R}^N$ but since the functions have zero boundary value they can be extended to a large ball where the embedding will hold, and therefore the restriction to $\Omega$ also embeds into $L^p$ compactly for $p<p^*$, as holds for smooth domains.

Comment: @Daniel, what disturbs me in this argument is only that the ball depends on the functions. 

Comment: @Daniel I am not sure that you can extend a $H^1$-function defined on a domain that is arbitrarily ugly to another $H^1$-function defined in the whole space, or in a ball. 
(Indeed, extending the given function in a reasonable way is exactly the main difficulty in proving compactness results).

Comment: (say, to get extactly that extension Brezis needs a $C^1$ boundary in his book, and his proof is still not straightforward).

Answer (score 3):

You can find a rather general answer in the book of Adams and Fournier, Theorem 6.16. You do have the embedding you wish, under a mild measure theoretical assumption.